# How can I get the sale_order.id from sale_order_line onchange method? In odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want to get the **id** value of **sale.order** from a sale.order.line onchange method.

I have this code:

```py
class SaleOrderLineExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['sale.order.line']

    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('my_field')
    def my_field_change(self):

        related_sale_order = self.order_id
        print 'related_sale_order: ', related_sale_order
        print 'related_sale_order.id: ', related_sale_order.id
```

But the output that I have is this:

```
related_sale_order: sale.order(<openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f7566029810>,)
related_sale_order.id: <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f7566029810>
```

I can check other values of the sale order, but not the Id. Why is that and how can I get it?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas What definition? related_sale_order is the name of a var that I just created, like "aux"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in onchange method the frame pass d dummy object that have the values in the view in order to get the original record you do :

```
self._origin.related_sale_order.id
```

but you should keep in mind that the related sale order when you create a record is not yet saved in database you will keep getting the same result but in edit mode you will have the id.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Okay, that works. Now, If i want to check the edit value of other registers, how can I get them? Is it clear my question?

Comment: no please ask a question an provide some code and we will try to help you sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
class SaleOrderLineExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['sale.order.line']

    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('my_field')
    def my_field_change(self):

        related_sale_order = self.order_id.id
        print "related_sale_order " related_sale_order
```

Comment: That is exactly what am I doing, but you put it in one line instead of two.